# Seems that my router accessed one of my Linux systems, what does it mean?

Tags: fedora, logs, login, router, last

I just ran the `last` command on two of my systems and there are weird entries:

```
user pts/2        dsldevice.lan    Sun Dec 28 22:59:35 2014 - Tue Dec 30 00:40:41 2014 (1+01:41)
```

Notice: **dsldevice.lan** and not the remote ip, is this from within the network?

What does this mean when the router is the one who is login in? Does this mean that the router it self has initiated an remote login? In what case would the routers address be in the log and not the ip that is being logged in from?

My router is: "Technicolor TG589vn v2" on two networks. Are they resolving them self's to this address instead of the ip that is logging in?

Comment: This question would benefit from more details.  What router (make, model)?  Looking at the files in `/var/log`, what activity do you see around Dec 28 22:59:35 2014?

Comment: @John1024 Ok, I'm not near the system now but, I'll do it when I get there, thank's.

Comment: @John1024 Done.

Comment: What does `last -i` show for that entry?

Comment: @rickhg12hs It shows the resolved remote ip(external ip of the router in question), it is a ip I know, from my own network.

Comment: What you show as `user` in the `last` output, is that a valid user on your system?  Have you checked your firewall logs?  Does your router implement NAT? How does your router implement its firewall?  Does the router have any logs to inspect?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No that username is made up, as I think it's reckless to post my username of my system online. Thank's, I'll look into that.